# NestedScrollView Recyclerview scrolls by itself

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a NestedScrollView which contain RecyclerView  ,the RecyclerView auto scrolling , How to stop this?

i try add  "android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" parent but not working

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_list_cases"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you try adding the following attribute to your LinearLayout - setFocusableInTouchMode=true

Comment: Thank you but not work unfortunately :(

Comment: Hmm... can you the height for NestedScrollView to match_parent and height for the LinearLayout to wrap_content